# arpack++ error:Matrix data contain inconsistencies

Tags: arpack

I typed the example code from the "arpackpp.doc", and got a run time error like this:
[image]

here is my code:
[image]

and the matrix is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

well, I answer my question...
element of irow, which is pointer to an array of row indices of the nonzero elements contained in nzval, should start from 0 not 1.